# Multiply whole column with the field calculator in QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, features

I have a layer with the field **size**. I did some mistake with the value and now I need the values multiplied by 16.

But instead of going through 500 lines and recalculating them I would like QGIS to do that.

So I tried to mark all features and then I hit the field calculator. Now I selected to take the values and chosen the **size** column. In the expression I had **$Id * 16**.

But the result was that I got:
0
16
36

instead of e.g.:
47
38
67

So how can I take a whole column with simple operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about `"size" * 16` in the field calculator expression?

Comment: Ohh c'mon, so easy =) Where could I have found a tutorial for this very easy stuff. Found really nothing in terms of that. =/

Comment: I won't follow the discussion here unless you mark the answer as accepted :D. Honestly, I do not know where to find a guide for that. Here you have a list of functions to use http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/List_of_Field_Calculator_Functions

Comment: :O I was not aware of that. An extra suggestion: Make a copy of your vector data layer and start playing with and exploring functions in the field calculator, if you go to `Function list->Fields and Values` and double click on any attribute name, it will put it in the expression with the correct syntax. That's a way of learning.

Comment: I don't think I will need more than a simple recalculating, so it's fine with the basics. And it works as it should with the field calculator. So thanks.